# Lifing state up: Communicating from child component and upward

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try to modify a base component's variable from a child component. I find that I can only do it by strictly doing the following:

1: Base component must have defined an event handler, strictly a variable `onVariableChange` event handler, and have it assigned to a local function

2: Base component must have custom attribute `variable` that will be linked with the above `onVariableChange` function

3: Child component can now call the `this.props.onVariableChange()` to make the appropriate modification (from child to base)

in Base declaration:

`changeFn(){ //do Something }`

Base's render:

```
return <div> <Child variable={this.stateSomeVar} onVariableChange={this.changeFn} />
```

in Child:

```
this.props.onVarChange();
```

Why is that? Why can't we just call the custom function from child to base directly without the use of custom property?

Am I incorrectly understanding the React's documentation?

in Base:

```
childFnAnsweredByBase(){
   ...
}
render(){
  return <Child callFromChildFn={this.childFnAnsweredByBase} />
}
```

REF:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I try to modify a base component's variable from a child
>   component. I find that I can only do it by strictly doing the
>   following:

I think you mean with variable, base or more accurate parent component's state.

> 1: Base component must have defined an event handler, strictly a
>   variable onVariableChange event handler, and have it assigned to a
>   local function

I don't know what do you mean by saying "strictly", but yes in order to do that parent should have a handler method. The name here is not important, just pass this properly to your child component.

> 2: Base component must have custom attribute variable that will be
>   linked with the above onVariableChange function

This variable or state property doesn't need to be linked anywhere and you don't have to pass this to your child component. If child component will use it yes you can pass, but in order to change this in the parent component, it is not needed to be passed to the child.

> this.props.onVarChange();
>
> Why is that? Why can't we just call the custom function from child to
>   base directly without the use of custom property?

If you mean saying by "property" the value itself, again, you don't need to pass it to the child. But, if you mean `props`, then you should use like that since this function is a part of the child's `props`.

Here is an example of how you do it without passing the "variable":

```js
const Child = (props) => (
  <div>
    <input onChange={props.callFromChildFn} />
  </div>
);


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    someVar: "initial value",
  }
  childFnAnsweredByBase = event =>
    this.setState({ someVar: event.target.value })

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child callFromChildFn={this.childFnAnsweredByBase} />
        <p>someVar is: {this.state.someVar}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

> Am I incorrectly understanding the React's documentation?

Probably yes. Personally, I don't like that part of the documentation. They are trying to explain an edge case there. Two child components are syncing with some parent's state and show this value with an appropriate situation. Like, one of them shows this value as Fahrenheit and the other one shows it as Celcius. This is why they are passing the state variable (after some conversion) to these components.

In the example above we don't use this state variable in our child component, this is why we don't need it. Here is an example (just a simple, stupid example) showing that how can we use it and why the parent is passing it.

```js
const Child = (props) => {
  const { someNum, multiplyTheNumberBy, by } = props;
  const handleMultiply = () => {
    const newNum = someNum * by;
    multiplyTheNumberBy( newNum );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleMultiply}>Multiply Number By {by}</button>
    </div>
  );
}


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    someNum: 1,
  }
  
  multiplyTheNumberBy = valueFromChild =>
    this.setState({ someNum: valueFromChild })

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child 
        multiplyTheNumberBy={this.multiplyTheNumberBy}
        someNum={this.state.someNum}
        by={10}
        />
        <Child
          multiplyTheNumberBy={this.multiplyTheNumberBy}
          someNum={this.state.someNum}
          by={100}
        />
      <p>someNum is: {this.state.someNum}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Update after comments**

> Also, why do we have to assign const localFn = props.CallFromChildFn ?
>   why can't we just invoke this.props.CallFromChildFn directly? Or is it
>   supposed to be props.CallFromChildFn?

First things first. We use `this` in a class component, so for a functional component, it is not necessary. We can use our props as `props.something` instead of `this.props.something`.

Now, the second question is about applying the best practice for performance reasons. For a small app this may not be a problem but for larger apps which has multiple children, components may be problematic.

When defining your functions in a JSX prop, if you use an arrow function and invoke them immediately, or bind it to `this` there to use it properly, this function is recreated in every render. This is why use references to this functions instead of immediately invoke them somehow or use bind.

**Examples.**

Think about my first example.

```
<input onChange={props.callFromChildFn} />
```

Here, I used the reference of my function and it workes. Since I don't invoke any function here it is not recreated every time when my component renders. I would use it in this way:

```
<input onChange={e => props.callFromChildFn( e )} />
```

Here, we are using a callback for `onChange` as an arrow function. It takes an event and passes it to our `callFromChildFn` function. This works, too. But, since we used an arrow function here, this function is created in every render.

Let's see my second example.

```
const { someNum, multiplyTheNumberBy, by } = props;
  const handleMultiply = () => {
    const newNum = someNum * by;
    multiplyTheNumberBy( newNum );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleMultiply}>Multiply Number By {by}</button>
    </div>
```

Again, instead of using directly my function, I define a handler function here and use its reference. With this newly created function, I can do multiplication operation and use my `multiplyTheNumber` function from my props and pass it the calculated value. But again, I would use something like this:

```
const { someNum, multiplyTheNumberBy, by } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => multiplyTheNumberBy(someNum * by)}>Multiply Number By {by}</button>
    </div>
```

As you can see, without creating a new function we can use an `onClick` callback function and use our `multiplyTheNumberBy` from our props and do the multiplication directly there. But, this function also recreated in every render.

Yes, with the reference method we use a little more code and for small applications maybe this is not necessary. But, I like to use in this way.

Comment: Very thorough and clear explanation. What I missed in my attempt was that I was trying to invoke `this.props.CallFromChildFn` not directly from child render, but from a function, that child's render is invoking. As you clearly explain, if I wanted to do that I would have to assign `const localFn = props.CallFromChildFn` first. And now I can invoke this.localFn anywhere I want. Thank you so much for the very clear explanation.

Comment: You are welcome. Just to be clear actually, we are not invoking this function in the `render` method just using its reference. Do not invoke any function in the `render` method if it is updating the state. If you do so you get an infinite loop.

Comment: Got it. Also, why do we have to assign `const localFn = props.CallFromChildFn` ?  why can't we just invoke `this.props.CallFromChildFn`  directly? Or is it supposed to be `props.CallFromChildFn` ?

Comment: @theMobDog, I've updated my answer since explaining this here would be difficult :)